# error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\ppData\Local\Temp\.sonarqube\.static\csharp_1.11.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to figure out why my simple .net console application is not compiling.

When I compile my app using Visual Studio 2015, which I have repaired already, I get the following error messages in my error list:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\
>   \AppData\Local\Temp.sonarqube.static\csharp_1.11.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.dll'
>   could not be found    ConsoleApplication1 \ -201s\q_hme_09$\
>   \data\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\CSC 1   Active

Please note that I don't have any Sonar or SonarAnalyzer step in my compilation, nor anything like that is installed.

I really don't know on why it is searching for SonarAnalyzer.zip.

Any guesses?

Comment: Please refer the [ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenHeier I have corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching over the Internet and also repairing Visual Studio, I could not find the solution.

I search for the location where Visual Studio 2015 is installed.

The location is : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

I found one directory called .sonarqube. I deleted everything inside.

I can now recompile my project.